# Ink CLI Expected component to be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to figure out the Ink library to build a console application with Javascript, and I've used React before, but this isn't react. Some of the quirks are a bit confusing.

I have an app working with two very basic components, and I've started working on a more in-depth component. The first two simply run a terminal command to check for a version, and those work just fine. I'm wanting to list in a table a listing of folders in a specific folder.

Here is my Ui.js

```
'use strict';

const {h, Component, Color} = require('ink');
const importJsx = require('import-jsx');
const PropTypes = require('prop-types');
const ChildProcess = require('child_process');

const DockerCheck = importJsx('./components/docker-check');
const GitCheck = importJsx('./components/git-check');
const RepositoryList = importJsx('./components/repository-list');

class UI extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DockerCheck></DockerCheck>
                <GitCheck></GitCheck>
                <RepositoryList repoFolder='~/repoFolder' ></RepositoryList>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


module.exports = UI;
```

and the error is coming from the `RepositoryList` component, which is here:

```
'use strict';

const {h, Component, Color} = require('ink');
const fs = require('fs');

const PropTypes = require('prop-types');

const Table = require('ink-table');

class RepositoryList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            repos: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fs.readdir(this.props.repoFolder, (e, f) => {
            if(e){
                console.log(e);
            }else{
                this.setState({repos: f});
            }
        })
    }
    render(){
        let {repos} = this.state;

        return(
            <div><Table data={repos}></Table></div>
        );
    }
}
RepositoryList.propTypes = {
    repoFolder: PropTypes.string
}

module.exports = RepositoryList;
```

and the error I'm getting is here:

> [nodemon] starting `node cli.js`
>   /Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/h.js:8
>                   throw new TypeError(`Expected component to be a function, but received ${typeof component}. You may have forgotten to
>   export a component.`);
>                   ^
>
> TypeError: Expected component to be a function, but received object.
>   You may have forgotten to export a component.
>       at h (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/h.js:8:9)
>       at RepositoryList.render (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/components/repository-list.js:32:13)
>       at RepositoryList._render (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/component.js:54:15)
>       at mount (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/diff.js:36:35)
>       at diff (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/diff.js:136:3)
>       at diff (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/diff.js:163:21)
>       at diff (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/diff.js:163:21)
>       at build (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/renderer.js:10:9)
>       at Renderer.update (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/lib/renderer.js:25:20)
>       at exports.render (/Users/cjrutherford/other/ninkcli/node_modules/ink/index.js:61:14)
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

What am I missing to get the component to render properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this component must either be imported using the es6:

`import Table from 'ink-table';`

syntax or

`const Table = require('ink-table').default;`

[Issue on Github for Ink-Table](https://github.com/maticzav/ink-table/issues/5)